# Change livereload host

Tags: grunt

The default livereload host is 127.0.0.1, but I have the access problems to access the this host directly in WSL2. Need to change it to http://localhost:35729/livereload.js Found the solution to change it via app\etc\env.php - to add

```
system' => [
        'default' => [
            'design' => [
                'footer' => [
                    'absolute_footer' => '<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

but got Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:35729/livereload.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive error

Disabled Magent0_Csp, working well, console is clear

Is there some elegant method just to change livereload host via grunt config. hostname: 'localhost' in watch.js config doeasn't work?

Answer (score 1):

you can change the livereload host via the Grunt configuration.

Try this

```
'system' => [
'default' => [
    'design' => [
        'footer' => [
            'absolute_footer' => '<script src="<%= watch.options.livereload %>"></script>'
        ]
    ]
]]
```

Comment: That's not Grunt, that's app\etc\env.php